# Create calendar event in the default android calendar

Tags: java, android, events, date, calendar

I have the following code to do something when a button is pressed. I would like to be able to have the button create a calendar event for March 3rd, 2013 at 10:00 am.  All help is appreciated.

Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   // button.setOnClickListener(this);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {


             if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open calendar with help of Intent.

Below is code for setting event in Calendar application. you can only open Calendar activity with default Event field filled.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);
intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);
startActivity(intent);
```

Put above code in your button's onclick listener.

In addition, you must add these calendar permissions in your manifest.xml:

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"
```

Comment: Okay, so how would I add another event under the same button? I want to have multiple events generated.

Comment: make one function with above code, and call that function N number of time as you wish to add N number of events.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of this "function"?

Comment: do you want to add multiple(suppose 5)event under single click on your button or you want to add event when ever your button get clicked ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15471/discussion-between-android-coder-and-scorpioblue)

Comment: how to insert event without open the calendar ?

Answer (score 2):

Android Coder provides an easy way to finish this task

In addition, you must add permission in your manifest.xml to use calendar event

android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"

android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"

Comment: thanks for guiding me missing point, i will be happy if you edit my answer.